# How to constrain a value within a range?

Tags: algorithm, random

Currently struggling to figure out how to constrain a value within a range. Meaning, given the random number 219, how can I make sure it is modified to stay within the range of (2, 5).

Here is my current implementation

```
int min = 2;
int max = 5;
int constrainedValue = (randomValue % max) + min
```

The above example does not work because `(219 % 5) + 2 = (4) + 2 = 6` and obviously `6` is not within my required range.

The purpose of this is to convert a random number into a value that fits within my range. Therefore, I cannot simply mod by just the max or min, the value must be "random" in a sense.

Comment: What's the range (max and min values) of the `randomValue`?

Comment: Could be anything, but for my purposes, will always be larger than the max;

Comment: Why not directly use rand() function and pass `min` and `max` as it's parameters?

Comment: What programming language is your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two common ways to constrain a value:

1. Clamping: here we set the value to the upper bound of the range if it exceeds it, or to the lower bound of the range if it is under it. This can be easily written thus:

   ```
   upper_bound = 5;
   lower_bound = 2;
   value = max(lower_bound, min(upper_bound, value))
   ```
2. Wrapping: here we wrap the value back to the lower bound if it exceeds the upper bound. This is the one you were trying to accomplish with the modulo operation. The range of the modulo is `upper_bound - lower_bound + 1`:

   ```
   value = mod(value, upper_bound - lower_bound + 1) + lower_bound
   ```

   or

   ```
   value = mod(value - lower_bound, upper_bound - lower_bound) + lower_bound
   ```

Here you can see the behaviour of the two methods (1 = blue, 2 = red):

[image: graph showing the output of the two constraining methods]

Answer (score 0):

If the `randomValue` is an integer that the range is between -32,768 and 32,767.

Then the following will do the job,

```
int constrainedValue = (randomValue - -32,767) * (max - min) / (32,767 - -32,767) + min;
```

or equivalently,

```
int constrainedValue = (randomValue + 32,767) * (max - min) / (65,535) + min;
```

If the `randomValue` is an unsigned integer then change -32,767 with 0 and 32,767 with  65,535.